# How to set magento 2 sudo chown -R username:www-data

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, server-setup, file-permissions, magento2.4.6

I'm using AWS EC2 ubuntu 22.04 to install magento2.4.6, but I'm confused about `sudo chown -R user_name:www-data .`, what should the user_name be, `ubuntu` or `root`.
The default ssh user of ubuntu 22.04 is `ubuntu`.

[image]
[image]

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'demo12345679!';
mysql> CREATE USER 'magento'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'demo12345679!';
mysql> ALTER USER 'magento'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'demo12345679!';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'magento'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql -u magento -p
mysql> CREATE DATABASE magento;
```

```
ubuntu@ip-123-45-67-890:~$ cd /var/www/html
ubuntu@ip-123-45-67-890:/var/www/html$ ls -al
total 1892
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:20 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Apr 29 13:27 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     343 Apr 29 15:20 .editorconfig
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     214 Apr 29 15:20 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   11382 Apr 29 15:20 .htaccess.sample
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    1523 Apr 29 15:20 .php-cs-fixer.dist.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     101 Apr 29 15:20 .user.ini
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  766543 Apr 29 15:20 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     650 Apr 29 15:20 COPYING.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    2972 Apr 29 15:20 Gruntfile.js.sample
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   10364 Apr 29 15:20 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   10376 Apr 29 15:20 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     698 Apr 29 15:20 SECURITY.md
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:20 app
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     150 Apr 29 15:20 auth.json.sample
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:20 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    2803 Feb 23 14:14 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1025351 Apr 29 15:19 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:20 dev
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:20 generated
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      55 Apr 29 15:20 grunt-config.json.sample
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:20 lib
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    6957 Apr 29 15:20 nginx.conf.sample
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    1234 Apr 29 15:20 package.json.sample
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:20 phpserver
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:20 pub
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:20 setup
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:20 var
drwxr-xr-x 75 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:20 vendor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to set `root` as the file system owner for Magento files and directories. To keep your server safe, it is better to use another file system owner (the command-line user) with fewer permissions. In your case, the command-line user is `ubuntu`.

Let's consider a scenario where you must share your credentials with someone who will log in to your server to fix or check Magento issues. However, they **accidentally** remove **the system directories** instead of the Magento directory. For example, they run `rm -rf /var` instead of `rm -rf var`.

To set ownership for two users, you need to:

1. Create the file system owner. In your case, your server has created a user named `ubuntu`.
2. Put the file system owner in the web server group.

- CentOS: `usermod -a -G apache <username>`
- Ubuntu: `usermod -a -G www-data <username>`. In your case, `usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu`. Yeah, you've done this one in the previous topic.

3. Set ownership for the shared group

```
chown -R :<web server group> /path/to/Magento/directory
```

In your case, Magento directory is `/var/www/html`, you need to run `chown -R :www-data /var/www/html`

**Note:** in case you set the ownership to the **wrong user**, you can use

```
chown -R <username>:<web server group> /path/to/Magento/directory
```

For example, assuming you want to set ownership for the Magen directory in `/var/www/html` to `ubuntu` user:

```
chown -R ubuntu:www-data /var/www/html
```

Then in the commands to set permissions for files and directories, you **should not** use `sudo`, otherwise it will lead to a permission issue when compiling code with `bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

For example:

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
```

Read more about "Configure file ownership and permissions" from the Magento official developer document: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/file-system/configure-permissions.html?lang=en

Comment: Thank you so much for describing it so clearly. I didn't change the user, but I found out that magento's file user is root. I have updated the question details.

Comment: @Angelo You're welcome. I've seen your updated information for the current Magento directory, you need to switch to `root` user and run this command to change the ownership to `ubuntu` user: `chown -R ubuntu:www-data /var/www/html` as I mentioned in my answer above.

Comment: Run `chown -R ubuntu:www-data .` in case you are in the Magento root directory, in your case, it is **/var/www/html**. If you are in another directory, you should add the path for the Magento root directory in that command: `chown -R ubuntu:www-data /var/www/html`

Comment: Like this, right? ubuntu@ip-123-45-67-890:/$ su root [next line] root@ip-123-45-67-890:/$ `chown -R ubuntu:www-data /var/www/html`

Comment: @Angelo Yep, that's right.

Comment: When I switch to the root user, it prompts that a password is required, but the AWS EC 2 ubuntu ssh user does not have a password. How can I obtain the password? Do I have to switch to root to change directory permissions? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html

Comment: @Angelo I'm not too familiar with AWS, you already switched to the `root` user successfully a few days ago, could you try again? https://repost.aws/questions/QUBt8ZgC76Rt6kDkzcqWlTGA/magento2-4-6-sftp-cannot-access-var-www-html-how-to-modify-the-permissions-of-html-files#:~:text=45%2D6%2D78%3A/%24-,su%20root,-Password%3A%0Aroot%40ip

Comment: OK, thanks. But they are not the same deployment method.

Answer (score 1):

`chown` changes the **owner** a file or directory, not its permissions. so if the current user is the same user you have simply **ignore** this command and everything will run great.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't change the user, but I found out that magento's file user is root. I have updated the question details.